# Positioning the FloatingActionButton in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I recently encountered a small problem I haven't been able to solve. I tried recreating the flutter default app using a stateful widget, I defined the `body()` of the app in the stateful widget and returned a `Center()`. The problem now is that the `FloatingActionButton()` is centered too.
**I've tried**
Using wrapping it in a `Padding()` but I can only change the values for the left and right values without distorting the UI of the app [The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4YxG.jpg)  [My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMmc0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Scaffold`s `floatingActionButton` property instead of embedding it inside the `body` of the `Scaffold`

```
 Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. It worked well for the positioning, but since the ```FloatingActionButton``` is used outside the stateful widget how can I make it functional

Comment: you can place your Scaffold along with your floating action button and more inside your stateful widget

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked when I placed the Scaffold in the stateful widget, just as you said

Comment: No problem ! glad u did it

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have placed a floating action button in your body part. That's why when you centered the widget a Floating Action button is centered Too. You can use the default property of Scaffold for your app.

```
Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text("Hello Flutter"),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.plus)),
  ),
```

This will solve your Issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since I'm using the `FloatingActionButton()` outside the stateless widget how can I make it have a functionality